# c# WebRequest using WebBrowser cookie

Tags: c#, browser, webrequest

I am logging into a site using a WebBrowser, then i want use regex to get some data , but webRequest didnt use web Browse cookie ,

my webBrowser is in public , 
is there any way to using WebBrowser cookie in webRequest ?

Comment: really simple i want use it for getting news :) but site protected by login page , so this way easiest to login :)

Answer (score 12):

```
    public CookieContainer GetCookieContainer()
    {
        CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();

        foreach (string cookie in webBrowser1.Document.Cookie.Split(';'))
        {
            string name = cookie.Split('=')[0];
            string value = cookie.Substring(name.Length + 1);
            string path = "/";
            string domain = ".google.com"; //change to your domain name
            container.Add(new Cookie(name.Trim(), value.Trim(), path, domain));
        }

        return container;
    }
```

This will work on most sites, however sites that use subdomains might be a problem.

Comment: This solution does not seem to work anymore because of cookies using the "httponly" modifier. That makes them invisible from scripting.

Comment: You can access the HttpOnly cookies through InternetGetCookieEx

Answer (score 7):

You can use a CookieContainer for a Webrequest.

```
 web_cookies = new CookieContainer();
 // Create a 'WebRequest' object with the specified url.                 
 HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

 myWebRequest.CookieContainer = web_cookies;
```

Hope this helps.

Ok, you want to do a log in. Thats is different story. You can use NetworkCredential for that.

```
public string get_secure_webpage(string url, string username, string password)
    {
        WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
        NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        myWebRequest.Credentials = networkCredential;
```

...

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you want to do.
Maybe this page will help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx

Comment: Actually, most websites use cookies for auth rather than HTTP auth, so using a networkCredential won't help. Attaching the cookie container will work so long as it gets the IE cookies; if not, PInvoke to InternetGetCookie()

Comment: this is tottally outside the question. useless

Answer (score 0):

is this silverlight?
if so, since silverlight 3 if you use the browser network stack than you should get cookies for free.  By default you get the browser stack when you create n HttpWebrequest using the WebRequest.Create() method.  note if you use CreateHTTP method, you get a client stack, which does not include browser cookies by default (you have to do trickery to get them, as described previously)

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920295(VS.95).aspx about the network stacks in silverlight since version 3