# Getting webbrowser cookies to log in

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, webbrowser-control

I am creating an windows forms app, where I have a `webbrowser control`.

After user logs in with the `webbrowser`, I want to log in also with same account with `Microsoft.Http.HttpClient` or `HttpWebRequest` or similar, it should be similar to `cURL` from `PHP`.

Problem is that the webpage allows only single sign on per account and if I sign with HttpClient, it will kick the webbrowser out.

What I want to know, if it is possible to hijack `webbrowser` session or get the `cookies` and use it in my `HttpClient` or similar `api`.

I can use `webbrowser.Cookie` to get some data, but how to push it to `HttpClient`?

Is that kind of thing even possible, that I can just take the cookies and use the same session? If so, how?

Comment: If the cookies are HttpOnly cookies then the webbrowser will not store them. See [IEGetProtectedModeCookie](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196998(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Got help from here:

[Is it possible to transfer authentication from Webbrowser to WebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382498/is-it-possible-to-transfer-authentication-from-webbrowser-to-webrequest)

Alkampfer posted solution. This is exactly what I needed and it worked.

This solution also takes `Http only` cookies.

> You can call the GetUriCookieContainer method that returns you a CookieContainer that can be used for subsequent call with WebRequest object.

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool InternetGetCookieEx(
        string url, 
        string cookieName, 
        StringBuilder cookieData, 
        ref int size,
        Int32  dwFlags,
        IntPtr  lpReserved);

    private const Int32 InternetCookieHttponly = 0x2000;

/// <summary>
/// Gets the URI cookie container.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="uri">The URI.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static CookieContainer GetUriCookieContainer(Uri uri)
{
    CookieContainer cookies = null;
    // Determine the size of the cookie
    int datasize = 8192 * 16;
    StringBuilder cookieData = new StringBuilder(datasize);
    if (!InternetGetCookieEx(uri.ToString(), null, cookieData, ref datasize, InternetCookieHttponly, IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        if (datasize < 0)
            return null;
        // Allocate stringbuilder large enough to hold the cookie
        cookieData = new StringBuilder(datasize);
        if (!InternetGetCookieEx(
            uri.ToString(),
            null, cookieData, 
            ref datasize, 
            InternetCookieHttponly, 
            IntPtr.Zero))
            return null;
    }
    if (cookieData.Length > 0)
    {
        cookies = new CookieContainer();
        cookies.SetCookies(uri, cookieData.ToString().Replace(';', ','));
    }
    return cookies;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can, but it's a bit tricky. Use the InternetSetCookie call together with a CookieContainer from HttpWebRequest.

Here's the method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385107(v=vs.85).aspx

and here's an example on how to set it: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/csharpgeneral/thread/76a38eee-3ef6-4993-a54d-3fecc4eb6cff

Comment: Hmm I am getting the cookies like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650536/c-sharp-webrequest-using-webbrowser-cookie , the second answer there , and setting to HttpWebRequest, but it isn't working, account isn't logged in.

Comment: Are you setting your own instance of the CookieContainer on the HttpWebRequest? This container should contain the cookie after doing the http request.

Comment: Ah sorry didn't see that you already solved the issue :)

Comment: @ThomasArdal, aren't cookies local to each browser and not per PC?

Comment: @old-geezer Sorry, but don't remember.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be stretching the technologies a little bit too far. The webbrowser control in windows forms are usually designed to give you basic html rendering from local files or internet, but it shouldn't be used to replace a full-fledge web browser.

If you want to authenticate against a SSO provider, then you have to use the right libraries, in this case from Windows Identitity Foundation, with Microsoft.IdentityModel you will get claims authentication mechanisms to handle the claims from your SSO provider. Cookies cannot be shared across applications, in fact some new web technologies are designed just to avoid that, so in my opinion try to use WIF instead of a webbrowser control.

Hope it helps,

Comment: I don't think its is `SSO provider`, they just have somekind of javascript thing or similar that blocks two connections to account in same time.

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
var cookies = new CookieContainer();
cookies.SetCookies(webBrowser.Document.Url, 
                          webBrowser.Document.Cookie.Replace(';', ','));
req.CookieContainer = cookies;
```