# Visual studio - Load a cookie and use in in WebBrowser when being on certain URL?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

How can i load cookie data to WebBrowser when i am on an URL like stackoverflow.com, in visual studio?
I already have my cookie file consisting of the required data to the stackoverflow login but I do not know how to make the WebBrowser use it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you [search for "webbrowser cookies" on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=webbrowser+cookies), you will get a couple of answers.  For example, [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14031887/623816) or [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15052664/623816). Your question appears to be a duplicate, but you're not alone :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a cookie in a WebBrowser control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830586/setting-a-cookie-in-a-webbrowser-control)